# Text being ignored when searching - datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm reducing the length of a string to 20 characters prior to adding the data to a datatable - http://www.datatables.net/. When I search the datatable(by typing into the search box) the truncated data is no longer searchable. Is it possible to add truncated data to a datatable without causing the datatable to ignore the truncated text when searching.

This is the code im using to add data to the datatable :

```
if(data.length > 20){
data= data.substring(0 , 20);
}
$('#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
data            
]
);
```

Problem is the data that is truncated is not searchable.

Comment: Need some clarifications.  What does this mean? - "When I search the datatable the truncated data is no longer searchable".  Also what library is `dataTable()` part of?

Comment: Hiya @user470184 I might have solution for you; Correct me if I am wrong but you want the column to show only partial text but the data table to search for the hidden text in your column? :) I have a sample Jsfiddle all set for your need if thats what you want, (d'uh - using datatable obviously) :) Have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit Yes, thats what im looking for, thanks

Comment: Saweet gimme a sec bruv, its a fork from an old solution but changed for your **Specific** use , cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya **Working Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/Gnazp/5/

search for foobar1 or foobar2 etc which are hidden on the table display but they are part of the column as you can see in jsfiddle code.

You can read the comment in the code but essentially the trick that code is doing is to bind the data with the filter first so that the filter has info about your full text and then truncate the string, so it appears as ou want it yo appear: (If you will truncate the string before filter it will forget about the data you got in your substring, hope the sample code will exaplain better in jsfiddle)

Note: Please let me know I can copy paste all the code here in my post.

**Explanation**

in this case:

```
<td class="truncatethis">test yes you can, foobar foonewbar.</td>
```

Only displays: `test yes y` on the datatable screen but if you search for `foobar` it will give you the correct results.

To display the truncated screen I have called the substring method after the filter is called: Look for the code at the bottom of that jsfiddle:

```
$(".truncatethis").each(function(){

    if($(this).text().length > 10){
               //alert($(this).html());
               $(this).html($(this).text().substring(0 , 10));
        }

});​
```

Hope this helps, Cheers!